# If catalog name is empty for DatabaseMetaDatagetProcedureColumns(), ResultSet.close() won't release oracle cursors

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ojdbc

```
String catalog = null;
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = connection.getMetaData ();
rs =  dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns ("", null, "procName", null);
rs.close ();

String catalog = "";
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = connection.getMetaData ();
rs =  dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns , null, "procName", null);
rs.close ();
```

rs.close() method won't release cursor to database, If I pass catalog name as empty String.
for the same If I pass null, rs.close() will close cursors.

why the difference?

Comment: May be connection pool is used and method `close` is overridden and it only returns connection to pool.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan, No connection pool is not used. this is very direct.